# R apply raster function to a list of characters

Tags: r, list, function, matrix, raster

I started recently to work with R so this question has probably a simple solution.
I have some .tif satellite images from different scenes. I can create a test raster brick with it but the process needs to be automatised because of the huge amount of files. Therefore I have been trying to create a function to read the list of .tif files and to output a list of rasters.
You can find here below the code I have been using:

```
# Description: Prepare a raster brick with ordered acquisitions 
# from all the scenes of the study area

library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(rtiff)

rm(list = ls())

setwd=getwd()

# If you want to download the .tif files of the 2 scenes from dropbox:
dl_from_dropbox <- function(x, key) {
  require(RCurl)
  bin <- getBinaryURL(paste0("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/", key, "/", x),
                      ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
  con <- file(x, open = "wb")
  writeBin(bin, con)
  close(con)
  message(noquote(paste(x, "read into", getwd())))                        
}

dl_from_dropbox("lndsr.LT52210611985245CUB00-vi.NDVI.tif", "qb1bap9rghwivwy")
dl_from_dropbox("lndsr.LT52210611985309CUB00-vi.NDVI.tif", "sbhcffotirwnnc6")
dl_from_dropbox("lndsr.LT52210611987283CUB00-vi.NDVI.tif", "2zrkoo00ngigfzm")

dl_from_dropbox("lndsr.LT42240631992198XXX02-vi.NDVI.tif", "gx0ctxn2mca3u5v")
dl_from_dropbox("lndsr.LT42240631992214XXX02-vi.NDVI.tif", "pqnjw2dpz9beeo5")
dl_from_dropbox("lndsr.LT52240631986157CUB02-vi.NDVI.tif", "rrka10yaktv8la8")


# 1- Create a list of .tif files with names ordered chronologically (for time series analysis later on)
 pathdir=  # change
# List all the images from any scene in that folder and
# make a dataframe with a column for the date
a <- list.files(path=pathdir,pattern="lndsr.LT", all.files=FALSE,full.names=FALSE)
a1 <- as.data.frame(a, row.names=NULL, optional=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # class(a1$a)  #   character
# Create date column with julean date and order it in ascending order
a1$date <- substr(a1$a, 16, 22) # class(a1$date) = character
a1 <- a1[order(a1$date),] 
# Keep only the column with the name of the scene
a1 <- subset(a1, select=1) # class(a1$a): character
# retrieve an ordered list from the dataframe
ord_dates <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(a1$a)))  # length(ord_dates): 4 (correct)
# class(odd_dates) # list

# 2- Create rasters from elements of a list
for (i in 1:(length(ord_dates))){
  # Point to each individual .tif file
  tif_file <- ord_dates[i]  # Problem: accesses only the first item of ord_dates
  # Make a raster out of it
  r <- raster(tif_file)  # we cant use here a list as an input. Gives error:
      # Error in .local(x, ...) : list has no "x"
  # Give it a standardised name (r1,r2,r3, etc)
  name <- paste("r", 1:length(ord_dates),sep = "")
  # Write the raster to file
  writeRaster (r , filename = name,format = "GTiff", overwrite =T )
}
```

I have also tried to use lapply() without much success.

```
r = lapply(ord_dates, raster)
```

Can you give me an advice on what concept to follow? I am guessing I should be using matrices but I don't really understand which are their advantages here or in what step they are required.

Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `ord_dates` is a list of file names (that have full path or are in your `getwd()`), you can apply a (any) function to this list using `lapply`. I haven't tested this, unfortunately.

```
convertAllToRaster <- function(tif_file) {
  r <- raster(tif_file)
  # Give it a standardised name (r1,r2,r3, etc)
  name <- paste("r", 1:length(ord_dates),sep = "")
  # Write the raster to file
  writeRaster (r , filename = name,format = "GTiff", overwrite =T )
  message("Eeee, maybe it was written successfully.")
}

lapply(ord_dates, FUN = convertAllToRaster)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help Roman!

I tried and a familiar error came up when using lapply(). It returns:
    Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
       unable to find an inherited method for function ‘raster’ for    signature ‘"factor"’.


I dont understand where the signature factor is created, because I thought to have fixed it earlier by making sure the lists were of class character, and not factor..

Comment: Your list elements are probably factors. In any case, insert a `browser()` in front of the line (or at the beginning of a function) you wish to examine, and then run your code. You should explore the environment of the function, execute code by hand and track down you bug in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

After solving the issues with factors and with the name, this is the code that worked for me. I added a for loop also inside the function you proposed, Roman. Thankyou very much for your kind help!!

```
convertAllToRaster <- function(ord_dates) {
  for (i in 1:(length(ord_dates))){
    tif_file <- ord_dates[i]
    r <- raster(tif_file)
  # Keep the original name
    name <- paste(tif_file, ".grd", sep ="")
  # Write the raster to file
    writeRaster (r , filename = name,format = "raster", overwrite =T ) # in .grd format
  }
}

lapply(ord_dates, FUN = convertAllToRaster)
```